# How to configure munin contact; keeps sending alert emails to root

Tags: email, munin

I have munin v1.4.6 setup on Ubuntu Server 12.04 and configured correctly: the graphs display and munin logs show no errors. However, it keeps emailing the root user instead of my personal email. My /etc/munin/munin.conf has the following contact:

```
contact.joe.command mail -s "Munin notification" xxxx@gmail.com
```

When munin runs, I see the following in my /var/log/mail.log:

```
Aug 26 13:35:34 joe-computer postfix/local[15964]: 581812DFD: to=<root@joe-computer>, orig_to=<root>, relay=local, delay=0.06, delays=0.04/0.01/0/0.01, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
```

Can anyone help me figure out why it is not mailing "xxxx@gmail.com"?

Comment: I ran `dpkg -L munin` and saw the cron for Munin is installed in /etc/cron.d/munin and /etc/cron.d/munin-node. I changed the `MAILTO` in those files to my email, and now I am getting emails. However, my question remains, why doesn't the contact directive in the Munin config work?